# Show that if $X$ and $Y$ are connected, then $X \times Y$ is also connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Show that if $X$ and $Y$ are connected, then $X \times Y$ is also connected.

Since $X$ and $Y$ are both connected they're the only components of themselfs.

Suppose that $X \times Y$ is disconnected that is $$X \times Y = G \cup H$$ with $G \cap H = \emptyset$.

Picking $(a,b) \in X \times Y \implies (a,b) \in G \cup H$. So either $(a,b) \in G$ or $(a,b) \in H$. Now wlog suppose that $(a,b) \in G$.

What I would like to express now is that $H$ must be the cartesian product of either $2$ seperate components of $X$ and $Y$ or that either $X$ has two components or $Y$.

This would lead to a contradiction with the statement that both $X$ and $Y$ are the only components of themselfs.

How can I express this mathematically?

Comment: There must be further conditions on $G$ and $H$, otherwise any set would be disconnected.

Comment: $G \cup H$ should be open in $X \times Y$?

Comment: Don't guess, look at the definition

Comment: Not quite. If $G\cup H = X\times Y$, then $G\cup H$ is obviously open.

Comment: @jjagmath the definition I have is that a subset $A$ of $X$ is disconnected if there exists open subsets $G$ and $H$ of $X$ such that $A \cap G$ and $A \cap H$ are disjoint non-empty sets with $A$ as their union. So following this $G$ and $H$ should be open in the "universal" space containing $X \times Y$.

Comment: Might be helpful to keep in mind (or prove) that the image of a connected space under a continuous function is continuous.

Comment: You also want $G$ and $H\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: @Janisch So if you know that $G$ and $H$ must satisfy all those conditions why in your proof you only mentioned $X\times Y = G \cup H$ and $G \cap H = \emptyset$? If you don't use all the properties that $G$ and $H$ have, you'll be not using your supposition that $X\times Y$ is disconnected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** How many connected components does $\{a\}\times Y$ have?

Comment: Only $1$ since it's homeomorphic to $Y$. Using these products I can complete the proof, but I'm wondering if there is a way to complete it with the contradiction approach I took.

Comment: You can keep using contradiciton to show that either $\{a\}\times Y$ has several components, or that $X\times \{y\}$ does for some $y\in Y$ (otherwise $G=X\times Y$, which contradicts the assumptions).

Answer (score 1):

Let $f: X \times Y \to \{0,1\}$ be continuous.

Pick $x_0 \in X$ and $y_0 \in Y$ arbitrary (both spaces are non-empty WLOG).

As $X \times \{y_0\} \simeq X$ (so connected) we have that for some $i_0 \in \{0,1\}$ we have $$\forall x \in X: f(x,y_0) = i_0\tag{1}$$

Now for each $x \in X$ we have that $\{x\} \times Y \simeq Y$ (so connected) and we have that $f\restriction_{\{x\} \times Y}$ is constant so for any $y$: $f(x,y) = f(x,y_0) =i_0$. This holds for all $x \in X$ so

$$\forall x \in X : \forall y \in Y: f(x,y) = i_0$$

and $f$ is constant, as required and $X \times Y$ is connected.